# Known plain-text attack on Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, known-plaintext-attack

This is a form of the Kerberos protocol[image]

I have two questions. Why does this protocol give the opportunity of a known plain-text attack because of no authentication of Joe? And how would an attacker perform a known plain-text attack?